# Why must Extends be the first property in a mootools class definition?

Tags: javascript, mootools

The [mootools docs](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Class/Class#Class%3aconstructor) state that "The Extends property should be the first property in a class definition.". After hours of investigation I stumbled upon this line in the mootools doc.

Although my original problem could be solved after settings Extends as the first property I do not understand why.

According to the js docs the order of properties in an object is subject of engine implementation. No guarantee of any kind is made about the order.

So why does mootools rely on the order? Trying to read the mootools code did not help me ;).

Comment: The order tends to be stable in modern JS implementations, but if I personally had anything to do with Mootools maintenance I'd consider this an outrageously bad architectural decision and insist it be fixed.

Comment: it's not at all outrageous, if you read the source and understand the consequences of having special mutator properties that change your constructor object. extends defines your prototype. if you did that in the vanilla way, it makes sense to set it early. its a `for (var in obj)` in loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, understand this: the MooTools Class constructor takes the simple object that you pass to it and then loops through the properties

Let's start with `implement` - https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Class/Class.js#L75 - is being called against all properties passed to the Class constructor. It is an overloaded function - see https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Class/Class.js#L98 - which allows it to work with an object of key -> value pairs. **the `overloadSetter` uses standard `for (var key in obj)` loop, which in most implementations will be FIFO - disregarding webkit's weird tendency to sort keys and return those that have numeric indexes or start with numeric chars first. ECMA spec does not guarantee order of properties**

When looping through object properties, it will try to look through the mutators defined under `Class.Mutators` - `Extends` and `Implements` - https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Class/Class.js#L100-L113

In the case of extends, it will set the `parent` property and also set the prototype of your new object constructor - https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Class/Class.js#L103-L104 - and this needs to happen early on. *It does not specifically pluck `Extends`/`Implements` because it was built to be extendible and to allow you to add your own custom Mutators, eg. `Binds` in MooTools-more - perhaps not the only solution, but some things are better left as awkward yet flexible API, as opposed to rigid and non-DRY sugar*

Particularly, things will break when `Implements` is before `Extends` as `Implements` will actually ... nevermind - I have described that in a blog post a very long time ago when I first encountered it - but spoke to a few MooTools core devs and it became clear why. See what I had to go through here: http://fragged.org/mootools-pattern-fun-class-implements-extends-at-the-same-time_1359.html

Arguably, things were better in the now defunct mootools-2.0 AMD branch here- https://github.com/kamicane/mootools-core/blob/define-2/Source/Core/Class.js#L19

So - for now, we need to live with it - until Prime is out anyway.